# Does the kernel delete entries in /dev on an initramfs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, devices, initramfs

I have a fully custom, minimal, embedded Linux (vanilla, 3.3.8, i486, Vortex86dx) system that boots from an initramfs image. No standard distribution scripts are used, just a single rcS file that does the initialisation.

I have an IDE Flash disk with two partitions at /dev/hda1 and /dev/hda2.

As this is a minimal embedded distribution for a fixed system, it has a static /dev directory that contains /dev/hda1 and /dev/hda2, and there is no UDEV.

At the point that init calls rcS, the /dev/hda1 entry is no longer present. No other scripts, user applications or daemons have been run at this point. /dev/hda1 *appears* to have been deleted by the kernel(?)

I do not have this same problem if I boot my target via an NFS root filing system during my development process.

I use Buildroot to create the /dev directory via the device_table_dev.txt file. e.g.

```
# IDE Devices
/dev/hda    b   640 0   0   3   0   0   0   -
/dev/hda    b   640 0   0   3   1   1   1   4
```

I inspected the rootfs.tar.gz from Buildroot output/images. The /dev directory contains /dev/hda1:

```
brw-r-----  1 root root  3,   0 Jul  2 13:44 hda
brw-r-----  1 root root  3,   1 Jul  2 13:44 hda1
brw-r-----  1 root root  3,   2 Jul  2 13:44 hda2
brw-r-----  1 root root  3,   3 Jul  2 13:44 hda3
brw-r-----  1 root root  3,   4 Jul  2 13:44 hda4
```

My post-boot directory listing (done from within rcS, at the top of the script) on the target looks like this:

```
brw-r-----   1 root   root    3,   0 Jul  2 12:44 hda
brw-r-----   1 root   root    3,   2 Jul  2 12:44 hda2
brw-r-----   1 root   root    3,   3 Jul  2 12:44 hda3
brw-r-----   1 root   root    3,   4 Jul  2 12:44 hda4
```

/dev/hda1 is missing. /dev/hda2 is a partition on the same disk yet it is still there. Strange.

If I run the Busybox utility "mdev -s", it restores/dev/hda1 on the target and it works normally. e.g. I can mount it

Has anyone ever seen this behaviour before?

Does the kernel delete entries from /dev?

Comment: It may be helpful (for the benefit of others searching for solutions) to indicate that this is a completely custom-built system.

Answer (score 1):

The `udev` subsystem creates and mounts a `tmpfs` filesystem on `/dev` at boot time. The contents are populated by the kernel as devices are detected. Since `tmpfs` resides in virtual memory, it's not persistent so your changes don't survive across reboots. Even if you have a `/dev` already, mounting the new filesystem hides the directory and it looks like all your device specials have been deleted. They haven't, but the end result is the same: the specials aren't where you expect.

I suspect you'll find that your `hda` and `hdaX` entries have been replaced by `sda` and `sdaX` entries. Alternatively, check out `/proc/devices` and `/proc/partitions` to get the name `udev` assigns to the drive.

Sometimes, a quick & dirty solution like `fdisk -l /dev/[sh]d[a-z]` can help (works better if you have fewer than 26 disks of each type).

By the way, the naming scheme used by `udev` is standardised, and your static `/dev` could do worse than to follow the conventions. If `udev` thinks it's `/dev/sda`, go with that. You could escape potential weirdness and misunderstandings down the road.

Comment: This is a custom distribution for a fixed embedded target so it only needs a static /dev and there is no udev.

I only run mdev as the hotplug agent because I handle USB Flash drives.

The directory listing from the target was performed right after init was executed by the kernel. No other applications or daemons are running at this time.

Comment: Interesting! Well, the kernel has no reason to delete anything in `/dev`, so if you're not running `udev`, you should look at *userspace* code that might. And check if something's mounted on `/dev` anyway. Possibly remnants of an earlier `udev` startup? How pristine are the boot scripts?

Comment: The thing is 100% custom. There is no remnants of anything. The boot scripts are all my own doing. My /etc/init.d/rcS simply does this:
`#!/bin/sh
ls /dev ...` and I can see that `/dev/hda1` is missing. There is nothing else running before I list the `/dev` directory.

Comment: The only thing I can think of checking might be the `/etc/inittab` file which is the only user customisable script that gets called before `/etc/init.d/rcS`  AFAIK it only calls `/etc/init.d/rcS` but I did have some other mount scripts in there earlier, I may have left some cruft that I have forgotten about. I will have to check when I get back in to work tomorrow.

Comment: If the problem isn't in the full userspace, it must be somewhere in the `initramfs`. But it's definitely not the kernel's fault.

Comment: Yes, it's very odd. The exact same system mounted as NFS works correctly. But when I make an initramfs from the same files, it does something differnt. `inittab` was clean, it simply does `::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS`. Oh, well, I'm going to side step this problem by using `mdev -s` to create `/dev` at boot and use a minimal `/dev` with just `console` and `null` devices. Thanks for the help.